# make font size smaller when post title exceeds a limit

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress site, having a page products using visual composer post grid as in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhMpS.jpg). when the name of products become a bit longer it breaks into two line and distorts the height of column. How can I tell it to make font smaller if title got longer than width of the column?

Comment: Use the grid correctly. This is not the place for these types of questions. SO is a place to ask **code specific** questions

Comment: You could maybe take a look at element queries and see if they can help (they're like media queries, but instead of writing styles based on the width/height of the viewport you write queries based on the width/height of individual elements in the page). Failing that, you're probably looking at writing something in JavaScript to check the text width and apply a class to resize if it's too wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this will probably be awkward as you should be building responsive sites. Your text should readjust based on the screen reading the website, and if you are trying to define changes to make the text fit on one line you could be tweaking this over and over again.

I advise that you design around this and customise your layout rather than trying to change size based on text length, over and over again.

However, you could do something as follows within PHP/CSS.

Check the [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) on the [`get_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function. If the `strlen` is more than a specified amount (say 20) you'd add a class, otherwise ignore it. Then, you'd style that class responsively based on how you wanted to change the font.

You'd need to edit your theme to replace the Title with the following:

```
<?php 

$title = get_the_title();

if (strlen($title) >= 20) {
  <h1 class="longer-text-modifier">
} else {
  <h1>
}

  <?= $title; ?>
</h1>
```

With your CSS being

```
.longer-text-modifier {
  font-size: 16px; // or em or rem
}
```

Edit: This could also be done on the fly with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes it's gonna be a problem in responsive case. but because it's in some items, if work on the design parts, it changes the whole columns, and there will be too much unused white space. Your answer will probably fill the void. thanks again